# SQL Server DMV to measure performance between dates

Tags: sql-server, indexing

Hi I am using the query below to get data on slow running queries and frequently used queries. I'd like to filter it within a specified time period so I can compare the results of some indexes. Is this possible? Is there a filter I can add? Cheers.

```
SELECT TOP 20
GETDATE() AS "Collection Date",
qs.execution_count AS "Execution Count",
SUBSTRING(qt.text,qs.statement_start_offset/2 +1, 
             (CASE WHEN qs.statement_end_offset = -1 
                   THEN LEN(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), qt.text)) * 2 
                   ELSE qs.statement_end_offset END -
                        qs.statement_start_offset
             )/2
         ) AS "Query Text", 
 DB_NAME(qt.dbid) AS "DB Name",
 qs.total_worker_time AS "Total CPU Time",
 qs.total_worker_time/qs.execution_count AS "Avg CPU Time (ms)",     
 qs.total_physical_reads AS "Total Physical Reads",
 qs.total_physical_reads/qs.execution_count AS "Avg Physical Reads",
 qs.total_logical_reads AS "Total Logical Reads",
 qs.total_logical_reads/qs.execution_count AS "Avg Logical Reads",
 qs.total_logical_writes AS "Total Logical Writes",
 qs.total_logical_writes/qs.execution_count AS "Avg Logical Writes",
 qs.total_elapsed_time AS "Total Duration",
 qs.total_elapsed_time/qs.execution_count AS "Avg Duration (ms)",
 qp.query_plan AS "Plan"
 FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats AS qs 
 CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(qs.sql_handle) AS qt 
 CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_query_plan(qs.plan_handle) AS qp
 WHERE 
 qs.execution_count > 50 OR
 qs.total_worker_time/qs.execution_count > 100 OR
 qs.total_physical_reads/qs.execution_count > 1000 OR
 qs.total_logical_reads/qs.execution_count > 1000 OR
 qs.total_logical_writes/qs.execution_count > 1000 OR
 qs.total_elapsed_time/qs.execution_count > 1000
 ORDER BY 
 qs.execution_count DESC,
 qs.total_elapsed_time/qs.execution_count DESC,
 qs.total_worker_time/qs.execution_count DESC,
 qs.total_physical_reads/qs.execution_count DESC,
 qs.total_logical_reads/qs.execution_count DESC,
 qs.total_logical_writes/qs.execution_count DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Throw in this in your where condition:

```
and last_execution_time between '2015-07-30 03:26:03.020' and '2015-07-30 06:26:03.020'
```

Note: Edit the time range as per requirement.

Comment: But won't the stats for e.g. total_elapsed_time not be filtered?

Comment: @user1102550 I am sorry but I don't understand your question. The filter for last_excution_time will allow you to look at slow running queries executed only in the time frame used in your filter condition. Not sure if it will help.

Comment: Let's say I want to compare the average execution time on one day vs another after the application of some indexes. I only want that average to use queries that were done on that particular day. Last execution time doesn't do that it just will filter if the last execution was done on a specific day.